# What constrain to use when trying to have one type of something (ex.bank account) for each ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a ACCOUNTS table with account_id attribute as primary key, cookie_type_id as foreign key, and client_id as a foreign key. When trying to make sure that each client_id has no overlap in cookie_type_id (one client cannot make 2 chocolate cookies), should I be using UNIQUE contrain on foreign key like:

`ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS ADD UNIQUE cookie_type_id` ?
The problem is if the client_id is different, it's okay to have an overlap in cookie_type_id. In this case, what code should I use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also add `client_id` to the unique constraint to prevent a client to have the same `cookie_type_id`. in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS ADD UNIQUE unique_index(cookie_type_id, client_id);
```

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation, but it worked! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a unique constraint on the columns `client_id, cookie_type_id`